# Meteor Route dispatch never rendered warning

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

For route:

```
Router.route('/logout', function(){
    var self = this;
    Meteor.logout(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error loggin out!');
        }
        self.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

I receive this warning:

```
Route dispatch never rendered. Did you forget to call this.next() in an onBeforeAction?
```

What is problem?

Comment: `Router.route('/logout', function(){
    var self = this;
    Meteor.logout(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error loggin out!');
        }
        self.next();
        self.redirect('/');
    });
});` try with self.next();

Comment: @Ethaan Exception in delivering result of invoking 'logout': TypeError: object is not a function

Comment: try to wrap that function `Meteor.logout` inside the `data:function(){}` or `action`  seems like you can just declare that function on the router

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can take time to log the user out. You need a template to display during this. A route cannot exist without a template with iron router. Or at least iron router is not designed to work without one.

Your html:

```
<template name="logout">
    Logging you out. Please wait...
</template>
```

Your route:

```
Router.route('/logout', function(){
    Meteor.logout(function(err) {
        if (err) console.log('Error loggin out!');
        Router.go("/")
    });

    this.render("logout"):
});
```

Comment: Extremely helpful answer—the warning message sort of makes it sound like it always has something to do with `this.next()`, even though the actual warning is that nothing was rendered.